# Restore a computer to factory settings

Tags: windows-10, restore, factory-defaults

I have a gaming computer with the following specs :

- Intel i7-4770K
- Asus Z87-A
- GTX 780 (soon to be replaced by a 1060)
- 16GB DDR3
- 500GB Samsung 850 EVO SSD

I've had the CPU/motherboard/GPU/RAM for about 3 years, and the SSD is a bit newer. I also got a new PSU and ordered a new GPU that's set to arrive in about a week.

Throughout that time I went through a lot of hardware change and especially software change. I've installed Windows 7 on the first SSD that I got with the computer, then installed WIndows 7 on the 500GB SSD, then installed Windows 10 when it came out, I also messed around with Linux & a Hackintosh, so my partitions are all messed up and I have half a dozen booting options, most of them obsoletes (ex: bootloaders for a Linux partition that is no longer installed).

**Long story short, I'm getting a new GPU and I would like to do a clean install of Windows 10 and reset everything to as close to factory settings as I can. What is the best way to do this?**

I know that in the Windows 10 installation wizard I can delete & create new partitions, but I'd also like to get rid of the obsolete booting options, do a full cleanup of the drives and partitions to make sure everything is gonna be running smoothly.

Comment: Get a Linux live USB, nuke the drives, and disable legacy booting in the BIOS.

Comment: “What is the best way to do this?” - Download the current Windows 10 ISO, boot to the installation environment, delete all partitions then install Windows 10.  When prompted for a license key, skip that step, and proceed with the installation

Comment: As you suggested, deleting the old partitions is one step. To get rid of the broken boot options you need to go in to your BIOS settings and remove all the UEFI boot images listed there. Each OS install adds itself to the list, and you can clean it out there.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'll have a look in the BIOS settings. What's the benefits of doing it from a Linux live USB, @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams?

Comment: The fact that you will get full, unfettered access to your drives.

Comment: https://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=16716